# How to write this sentence about the square root of a matrix

Tags: syntactic-analysis, mathematics

Suppose in a math paper I formulated the following sentence:

> **The square root of the matrix *A*** is well-defined, **denoted** by √*A*…

A friend of mine told me that it sounds not correct.

Comment: Whether it's correct depends on the rest of the sentence. Can you include it?

Answer (score 3):

The words *defined* and *denoted* right after each other may cause a bit of confusion which can be resolved like this:

> The square root of the matrix *A*, denoted by √A, is well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your sentence. You use the appropriate punctuation (`,`) to give a break in the sentence letting the reader see that

> *denoted* by √*A*…

is the next part of the sentence and the word *denoted* belongs to √*A* joined by the word *by*

---

the sentence up to the comma is a complete thought and can stand on its own.

> The square root of the matrix *A* is well-defined.

Comment: “The square root of the matrix A is defined by √A” is a false statement, so will not remove confusion.  The root can be *denoted* by √A, but must be *defined* by some relation like (√A)² = A. (See [ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix))  Also note, [well-defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-defined) is a mathematical idiom, and its meaning is not deducible from meanings of  *well* and *defined*.